# Javascript - Range input

Tags: javascript, html, slider, range

Thanks for helping me guys!

I wish that in addition to the slider option, I could insert the number inside a box, so that it could be more direct. So besides the person doing the "thumb", she could enter a direct number as well.

Another question is: besides normal shipping, there will be two more options. I need to insert two more options, I tried to put more categories, but I could not. Because the shippings work as follows: Bronze Shipping: 1-65 lbs Silver Shipping: 1-10 lbs Gold Shipping: 1-4 lbs

So if the person entered 3 lbs, there were 3 shipping options, or if they put 55 lbs, only the Bronze Shipping option would appear.

If a button is needed to confirm the values ​​for the shipping options, that's OK!

Thanks for everyone's help, I've tried a lot of topics, but I can not do it the way I need it.

Code:

```js
let rangeValueElement = document.querySelector('#range');
let shippingValueElement = document.querySelector('#shipping');

function calculateShipping(price) {
  const priceShippingRelation = {
    1: 43.51,
    2: 47.05,
    3: 50.61,
    4: 54.15,
    5: 57.71,
    6: 61.25,
    7: 64.81,
    8: 68.35,
    9: 71.91,
    10: 75.45,
    11: 79.31,
    12: 83.15,
    13: 87.01,
    14: 90.85,
    15: 94.71,
    16: 98.55,
    17: 102.41,
    18: 106.25,
    19: 110.11,
    20: 113.95,
    21: 117.81,
    22: 121.65,
    23: 125.51,
    24: 129.35,
    25: 133.21,
    26: 137.05,
    27: 140.91,
    28: 144.75,
    29: 148.61,
    30: 152.45,
    31: 158.31,
    32: 160.15,
    33: 164.01,
    34: 167.85,
    35: 171.71,
    36: 175.55,
    37: 179.41,
    38: 183.25,
    39: 187.11,
    40: 190.95,
    /* ... */
    42: 136,
    /* ... */
    65: 220
  };

  return priceShippingRelation[price];
}

document.querySelector('input#valR').addEventListener('change', showVal);

function showVal() {
  rangeValueElement.innerText = this.value;
  shippingValueElement.innerText = 'Priority Mail (frete): $ ' + calculateShipping(this.value);
}

console.log(calculateShipping(3));
```

```html
<input id="valR" max="65" min="1" step="1" type="range" value="1">

<span id="range" class="tesxss">1</span>
<div class="tesxsss2">
  <div id="taxa">Taxa FS Connect: $15.00</div>
  <div id="shipping">Priority Mail (frete): 43.51</div>
```

Comment: You should simplify your priceShippingRelation. Would you also manually write write it if there were 120000 shippings and not 65?

Comment: @JapanGuy i dont understand, sorry...

Comment: Let's calculate by using a look up table. That's the kind of calculation I love the most. On a more serious, I'm looking for a question mark(?) in your post and I can't find it.